# Rails 3.1 - escaping user's input

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.1, escaping

Good day everyone!

How can i escape string of user's input from search form which'll use in sql query? I would like to do that in my controller.

For example, this:

```
Time is 10:15 pm.
```

Should be something like this:

```
Time is 10\:15 pm.
```

Note: i search in db (postgresql) by gem (texticle).

Answer (score 1):

[ERB::Util.html_escape](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-html_escape) will give you the full explanation :)

Comment: I am afraid that html_escape doesn't do what i want. It doesn't even escape above example from my post.